# Who or what are we?

Tags: riddle

One I made myself. Have fun!

*You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.*

*You can count on me as you always did!*

*The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.*

*I can stop the darkness!*

*If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!*

*I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!*

*Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.*

*Who or what are we?*

PLEASE use the spoiler tags!
Do it by putting **>!** in front of your sentences!

> Every line is a hint. Obviously ignore my introduction and the end part...

Comment: "You can count on me as you always did" makes me think of an abacus, but that doesn't seem to fit the rest of the lines...

Comment: "We are torn apart by *whom who* need us most."?

Comment: @d'alar'cop The rough meaning is equivalent to "by those who need us most". Perhaps this is an intentional choice of words?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Possibly, that's why I asked rather than just edit :p _But_ I'm fairly certain it's grammatically incorrect regardless. However since it's a riddle intentional word play doesn't need to adhere to grammar :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**My guess is**

> **Trees**

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> We all need trees for oxygen, rain, food, shelter and all

You can count on me as you always did!

> We depended on trees and made many things using trees even from ancient time.

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> The big bang that resulted in the formation of earth, which was an orange land because of the lack of water, plats and was red hot because of the heat.

I can stop the darkness!

> By lighting sticks, wood etc

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> Making fire with wood

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> Producing oxygen (oxygen molecule consist of two circle shaped oxygen atoms)

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> We cut down trees for various needs and polluted the environment which too will cause the trees to get extinct soon.

Comment: Which is your final guess? Suppose this is the correct answer and I tag it as such, which one of your answers would people have to read? ;)

Comment: The first one. Trees. Should I remove one or can I keep both?

Comment: You can keep both. Perhaps you should split them in 2 answers?

Comment: I have already did it

Comment: This is correct!
Almost all clues are correct.
More explained in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

> Hydrogen atoms on sun

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> They are turning to Helium, slowly decreasing in size.

You can count on me as you always did!

> We count days and nights

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> The fusions turning sun into an orange land

I can stop the darkness!

> Daylight

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> Warmth

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> Maybe sun and the reflection of the light from moon

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> Helium atoms need them to increase in size, but this destroys Hydrogen atoms

Answer (score 6):

> Maybe it is a MatchBox.

You can count on me as you always did!

> to light a fire.

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> this is how a matchstick lights up and fire color is orange.

I can stop the darkness!

> creates light so stops darkness

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> fire is warm

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> trying to figure this out. maybe it refers to the head portion of matchstick which is sphere like.

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> matchstick gets depleted as you use it up.

Who or what are we?

> so a matchbox with matchsticks.

Comment: nice answer. looks good

Comment: very good answer, but i think the 2 bound circle shapes ruin it

Comment: how about now? but 2 circles???

Comment: I like it, though I'd modify it _just slightly_ to fit the particular "torn apart" phrasing. (Don't want to be too specific in comments.) Also scratching my head about the circle-like shapes thing, though.

Comment: @Sp0T the dark bit and the orange bit: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/036/0/b/burning_match_by_aschmitt-d38uoxl.jpg

Comment: i like this answer, but I think you mean MatchBook... not box. A box of matches aren't 'torn apart'. The glowing spheres, maybe the head of the match and the fire around it. As in, the area between the match head and fire is transparent thus creating 2 sereate spheres.

Answer (score 3):

Who or what are we?

> We are Brains! (I know this is far-fetched)

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> Off-course we need them and as you age the no of neurons decrease so its like losing family.

You can count on me as you always did!

> We can take this literally as in counting in your head/brain.

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> So there was this sound recording company called [Brain_Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Records) and the wiki page says that - *"the labels of Brain LPs changed from green to orange"*. So the LP would be the metaphor for the orange land and it could have the recording of an explosion.

I can stop the darkness!

> Brains developed bulbs!

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> [mind over matter](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/04/130408084858.htm) - Its said that by using brain power we can regulate body temperature.

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> Eyes are the extension of brains through which we see life and they could be viewed as two bound circular shapes.

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> The more we use it the more structural changes happens inside the brain over the course of our lifetime so in-effect we are kind of tearing it as we use it.

I'm sure that this is not the intended answer but still want to share this.

Comment: I like your thought process! It might as well be the intended answer I am looking for. Or, perhaps it's completely wrong. I'll tell you in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> Stars:
>  We've always needed them, looks orange during rise and set, stops darkness, warms things, brings us life, (not sure about the 2 circle like shapes, rain drops & planets maybe indirectly provided by the sun) losing my family thanks to gravity stretching space-time tearing them away from each other , but they need gravity to hold them together.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret

> I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

as

> DNA, chromosomes, or genes - the double helix. Since they are made of proteins, you could also try proteins or molecules here, except that the OP has said molecules is not the intended answer.

How to make it fit the other clues?

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> Sure, we need DNA to keep making new blood, bones, skin etc as long as we live. As your ancestors die, your genes or DNA lose some of their family.

You can count on me as you always did!

> Same as you need me, really

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> I have nothing here. Perhaps "the orange land" is the Netherlands, who use orange as a symbol for sports teams etc, or Spain, where oranges grow. I can't see a way to have bang, boom, or other explosion sounds somehow "transfer" to another country so this clue mystifies me.

I can stop the darkness!

> Some species have genes for bioluminescence

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> And some for antifreeze-like properties

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> This is really the crucial clue for me as I said above

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> The first sentence is a repeat. The second might refer to the fact that each parent passes on only half their DNA to the offspring. It's "torn apart" to pass on half

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very similar to the one above, with one difference.

> I think it is a book of matches instead of a box of matches.

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> In a book of matches, you remove a match from the book to use it.

You can count on me as you always did!

> It is easy to count how many matches are left in the book.

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> The sound is the match igniting, and the flame is orange.

I can stop the darkness!

> Fire brings light. You can use a match to light a lantern.

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> Fire brings heat. You can use a match to light a bigger fire.

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> A flame has 2 parts, a cooler part near the head of the match and a hotter one at the end of the flame. The two parts of the flame are roughly circle shaped.

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> You have to tear a match out of the book. This is why I think it is a book as opposed to a box.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is

> Molecules?

It does make sense in almost every sentence.

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> **You need molecules for everything.**

You can count on me as you always did!

> **You always count on the molecules otherwise you couldn't even exist.**

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> **The state change of solid to gas and from gas to plasma which is orange (I believe so).**

I can stop the darkness!

> **Maybe has to do something with electricity.**

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> **If water reaches 100 degrees it becomes hot and so do the molecules**

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> **Don't understand this one**

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.
Who or what are we?

> **Clueless too for now**

Comment: Why can we "count on them as we always did" and what is the "orange land"?

Comment: Explain your thinking with every sentence ;). It is not my intended answer, but it might be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

**Another guess is**

> **WEDDING RINGS**

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> For proposing, During engagement or Marriage

You can count on me as you always did!

> All most all value and trust the wedding ring and considers it as an agreement with the life partner.

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> Making of the wedding ring, by heating and melting to make the metal to look like orange lava

I can stop the darkness!

> With the love from the partner

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> With the caring from the partner

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> Shape of two wedding rings/making love which will result in the birth of a baby

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> Divorces. Recent increase in number of divorces.

Comment: This is definitely not correct. Perhaps your other answer is? Or might I just be fooling around?

Comment: The first one. Trees. I have mentioned that in the comment on the other answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct answer:

> Tree(s)

*You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.*

> Trees can be used as wood, paper, for fire, ...

*You can count on me as you always did!*

> We can count on paper. Literally, write math on paper...

*The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.*

> This one is a tricky one. The sound of an explosion is *boom*. The orange land in fact points towards the Netherlands. Tree in Dutch is boom.

*I can stop the darkness!*

> When wood is lit, it gives you light.

*If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!*

> Again, when lit, it gives warmth.

*I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!*

> Refers to the formula of oxygen! Well found!

*Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.*

> Refers to people cutting down trees.

*Who or what are we?*

> Tree(s)!

Comment: "The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land." part was really brilliant. +1

Comment: Thanks, I thought people would think this was way to complicated :P.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could also be

> Heat / Atoms!

You need me. You need me in many ways. Yet, I'm slowly losing my family.

> Atoms are continuously splitting away from each other.

You can count on me as you always did!

> Quite general, but can also mean Humans constantly estimating the number of atoms. In a smaller sense, "measuring heat".

The sound of an explosion, transferred to the orange land.

> The BIG BANG

I can stop the darkness!

> Photons

If you want, I can even stop the bitter cold!

> Electrons vibrating produces heat

I bring you life as in 2 bound circle-like shapes!

> The nucleus and electrons!

[image: Atom]

Yet, I keep losing my family. We are torn apart by whom who need us most.

> Nature needs them the most and they are getting split from each other every moment!